# Getting input from user in the form of a command - Java

Tags: java, input, command

I would like to use a Java `Scanner` to get a command from the user in the form of *Command* *arg* *arg*
The args are separated by spaces.

I would like to write the command and args to a `String[]` called `command`.

I have now started and this is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Boot.boot();
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] command = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    String[] commandListOutput = Boot.command.commands.get(command[0]);
    Object[][] argsArray = new String[1][command.length - 1];
    Class<?>[] argsArrayClasses = new Class<?>[]{Object[].class};
    
    for(int i = 0; i > argsArray.length - 1; i++){
        if(i != 0){
            argsArray[0][i] = command[i];
        }
    }
    
    
    
    invokeMethod(commandListOutput[commandListOutput.length - 1], "command", argsArrayClasses, argsArray[0]);
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried :)

Comment: I dont know where to start so I really cant give that at this time.
I know i need a scanner and I know how to do that but from their on Im stuck.

Comment: `assertThat(question, containsString("?"))` => `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: a string containing "?" but: was "..."`

Comment: Aside from the fact that there isn't actually a question here, SO is not the place to ask other people to do your homework for you. If you have a [*genuine, on-topic*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) problem that you have tried to solve yourself first (and you can show us what you've done), then by all means [ask away](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands now, this isn't a good question.

Comment: hate to bump but im stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] command = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
```

assuming you are reading command from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

From the automation point of view, you should probably avoid this approach and create a CLI solution instead (avoiding manual interactions throughout the process), for that I recommend Apache CLI:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Even if you are doing this for academic purposes, you should probably leverage its argument parsing approach to help you with your own program.

Comment: Sorry but using this approach from my experience will most likely leave me more in the dark sorry I just don't know how to handle that kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way:

```
public static void main(String arguments[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
        System.out.println("Gimmi your args separated by spaces:");
        String[] args = scanner.next().trim().split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```